# Why can't we use Linearity of Expectations?

Tags: probability

Based on the following article: https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/
We know that: 
Linearity of expectation can be applied to **dependent** random variables.

"The digits 1,2,3 and 4 are randomly arranged to form two two-digit numbers, 
AB and CD. For example, we could have AB = 42 and CD = 13.  What is the expected value of AB*CD?"

Why can't we just multiply E[AB]*E[CD] if it's ok to apply Linearity of expectation on dependant variables?

Thanks

Comment: Linearity is an additive property, not a multiplicative one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @lulu and in the article, linearity of expectation is an additive property, not a multiplicative one.

By the way, if you were wondering how to solve the question you posed, note that there are $12$ different choices of $AB$ and $2$ choices of $CD$ for each choice of $AB.$ However, because of the commutative property of multiplication we only need to consider $12$ choices. These choices correspond to $(AB,CD)=(12,34),(12,43),(21,34),(21,43),(13,24),(13,42),(31,24),(31,42),(14,23),(14,32),(41,23),(41,32).$

Thus, the expected value of $AB\cdot CD$ is $705 \dfrac{5}{6}.$
Though @CalvinLin's solution is more efficient because it exploits the symmetry in the problem.

However your method would give $756.25.$

Comment: I'll upvote if you fix your calculation to match the other answer.

Comment: okay fine. I guess I sort of underestimated this question.

Comment: I just used the $12$ pairs you identified to confirm your method gives the same answer as @CalvinLin.

Comment: @J.G. my logic was correct, though perhaps a little inefficient, but I made a calculation error, so that's why I got the wrong answer.

Comment: Agreed. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

On the Brilliant wiki, you can click on "Reveal Solution". It states

1. Multiplicative linearity only pulls out for independent variables (which answers your question),
2. How we can creatively apply the linearity of expectation (which explains why we used that as an example for this wiki).

[image]